# What is the best way to get all the registers with "Today" date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I using MS SQL Sever and I want to filter my query by only "today" registers, example

```
select * from tbl where [FieldDate] >= "Today Date"
```

I know I can use something like:

```
[FieldDate] >= DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

or

```
[FieldDate] >= CAST(FLOOR( CAST( GETDATE() AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME)
```

But, what is the best way to do that?, thanks a lot.

Note: I can't use the "convert(date, getdate())".

Comment: Just saw your edit. Why can't you use `convert(date, getdate())`?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005, "Date" type doesn't exist.

Comment: @Coyolero Updated my answer for SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE [FieldDate] >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) 
AND [FieldDate] < CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()))
```

For SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE [FieldDate] >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) 
AND [FieldDate] < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()),112)
```

Comment: Yep, that works :) But I cant use the "Date" time, It doesn't exists in MS SQL server 2005

Comment: @Coyolero Yeap, I answered this when it was tagged with `sql-server-2008`

Comment: @Coyolero Updated my answer for SQL Server 2005

Comment: @Lamak why you applied `[FieldDate] >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) 
AND [FieldDate] < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()),112)` why not `DATEDIFF(DD, [FieldDate], getdate()) = 0` in WHERE clause

Comment: @vikas because that is the right way to do it. The field is `DATETIME`, so there is the time part that your answer isn't taking into account. And because this way if there is an index on `FieldDate`, the query can use it; your asnwer makes it unable to

Comment: @Lamak that's fine but @Coyolero wants Users registered today and `DATEDIFF(**DD**, [FieldDate], getdate()) = 0` shows diff bw day only right?

Comment: @vikas yes, that's right. In any case, that way you can't use an index if `FieldDate` has one

Comment: Thanks @Lamark your solution works for me, but using it would be better than "DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))"?

Comment: @Coyolero As I've said on the comments before, the benefit of doing it this way is that if there is an index on the column `[FieldDate]`, then this query can use it. If you really want to use `DATEADD(DATEDIFF....`, then by all means, do it

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DD, [FieldDate], getdate()) = 0
```

Comment: this will perform very slow

Comment: because you are making a calculation on all rows instead of just comparing the values in the field